Foreign key constraint lost in PostgreSQL table in Azure when data is added using R Script
I have a table in PostgreSQL database, hosted on Azure cloud. In this table, I have created foreign key constraints on multiiple columns.
I have a script in R which tries to push the contents of a dataframe in the above table in PostgreSQL database. Below given code is used to do the same in R :
db_con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                     dbname = 'abcd12', 
                     host = 'test1', 
                     port = 4567, 
                     user = 'user1',
                     password = 'pass1')

DBI::dbWriteTable(db_con,
              table_name,
              dataframe_name,
              row.names = F,
              overwrite = T)


where db_con = database connection string, table_name = name of table
in PostgreSQL DB, dataframe_name = name of dataframe in R

When I try to execute the above code, data from dataframe in R is pushed to DB in Azure but all the foreign key constraints are lost.
I am also aware of the fact that dbWriteTable drops the table completely when overwrite=TRUE. And this dropping the table breaks the foreign key constraint.
Is there maybe a way to do this, like overwriting the data from dataframe in R to table in DB in Azure ? Can someone please help me to do this ?
Is there also a possibility that I would be able to do this using combination of R and SQL ? Because in R, as per my knowledge, SQL queries can be written using sqldf package.
Any leads/hints in regards to above issue will be very helpful.

To ensure that foreign key constraints are not lost when updating the data in your PostgreSQL table, you should avoid using the overwrite = TRUE option in dbWriteTable as it drops and recreates the table, which indeed removes any constraints.
Instead, you can truncate the existing table and insert the new data from the R dataframe into the existing table by using the below R script:
library(DBI)
db_con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                    dbname = '<dbName>', 
                    host = '<serverName>', 
                    port = 5432, 
                    user = '<userName>',
                    password = '<password>')

# Prepare the data for insertion/updating
dataframe_name <- data.frame(
    parent_id = c(1, 2),
    description = c('Updated Child 1', 'Updated Child 2')
)

# Start a transaction
dbExecute(db_con, "BEGIN;")

# Step 1: Truncate the table to delete all rows while preserving constraints
dbExecute(db_con, "TRUNCATE TABLE <existingTableName>;")

# Insert data from dataframe to the table using dbWriteTable
dbWriteTable(db_con, '<existingTableName>', dataframe_name, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE) 

The table structure and foreign key constraints are preserved, and only the data is replaced as shown below:

